# How to setup a gateway to a Linksys router?

Tags: router, dsl, gateway, bridge-router

I have a Linksys router(WRT54G) and I recently got a gateway(dva-g3810BN/TL) from my DSL provider(telus).

I am having a huge trouble of hooking them up together as I want to use my router as the gateway/router I was given is limited in features.

When I try to plugin my router into the gateway I cannot access the internet, the gateway config page nor the the Linksys router.

What do I need to setup to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is corrected in my comments too.

<s>it probably wouldn't work 'cos DHCP is on both by default. You don't want that. You could turn DHCP off the second router. You want all IPs on your network to be in the same subnet.</s>
DHCP on both is fine there's no clash, because the DHCP from the isp gateway will not go past the linksys WRT54G to its LAN side.  DHCP on the isp gateway is useful though it'd only be sending to one device, so no worries if you can't turn it off on the isp gateway, it still even has its use. And on the linksys WRT54G it's very useful for sending to each of your computers.

<s>So no good if one device is 192.168.0.1/24  and another is 192.168.1.1/24 or 10.0.0.1</s> 
You do want that situation, devices on the LAN side of the linksys WRT54G to be on a different subnet to the one on the WAN side. That's with NAT on. And I have heard that without NAT on it loses other functionality and becomes just a switch.  So it's not great either way in that with NAT on both you'll have double NAT just means port forwarding can be more work to do. With NAT off on the linksys, you may lose functionality you want and then have no need for the linksys at all.  Ideally you want to turn NAT off on the isp gateway, maybe use a different router/modem to your ISPs if it can't do it. (Some ISPs try to force you to use theirs with testing the MAC address but some router/modems will apparently let you set the MAC manually or clone it from another device, and get around that.

You mentioned not having internet access. You can have internet access with double NAT it won't cause a problem there. It's just a bit more work with port forwarding if you want to run servers, and you're reliant on 2 things working and being configured right, rather than one when doing port forwarding.

<s>typical working examples would be, you might have a router of 192.168.0.1  , a computer of 192.168.0.2 another computer of 192.168.0.3</s>

or another working example , you might have a router of 192.168.1.1  , a computer of 192.168.1.2 another computer of 192.168.1.3

if a device connected to your router is not on a recognized subnet e.g. simple situation is the same subnet of the device.. Then I don't think that device will get online..

Have one router doing DHCP(handing out IPs) to all other devices. And don't have 2 routers doing DHCP or they'll clash while doing it.

Just so you're aware of the options, if however you did turn NAT off on your linksys WRT, then it'd be a switch and lose router functionality, and then if you still wanted to use it, you may not have a useful use for it, but if you still wanted to use it, then you'd want all devices in the same subnet, either set statically or  DHCP done by just one device (presumably the isp gateway), DHCP from 2 devices would clash. And with DHCP from the isp gateway it'd reach all of them, would go through your linksys WRT54G and to your computers. If it was your linksys WRT54G doing it, it'd go to all too.  That's with NAT off on your linksys.

Comment: @barlop - I disabled my routers(Linksys) so it is not sending DHCP but it still will not connect. I would prefer that my router be dishing out the ip's but I can't find how to disable it in the gateway. They both seem to be using 255.255.255.0 subnet

Comment: @chobo2  255.255.255.0 is a subnet mask not a subnet. are all routers/gateways and comps on 192.168.0.x  or 192.168.1.x  or a mix?  btw router and gateway i think mean the same thing,  but i see you refer to the isp one as a gateway/the gateway - ok.

Comment: @chobo2 you may  have to tell your linksys to get its IP via DHCP .  At the moment it may be statically set to an IP in a different subnet

Comment: i suppose isp ones are commonly called gateways  but more specific/technical term would be router/modem.

Comment: @barlop - mine is like 192.168.1.1 and theirs when I am connected to it is like 192.168.1.254. and my ip is like 192.168.1.107. I will look for how it grabs it's dhcp as right now I don't know how. I usually just gave it a starting ip.

Comment: @chobo2  looks like static and coincidentally the same subnet. so shouldn't be an issue but still worth setting to DHCP and seeing it's then at least getting the ip from the isp-gateway. btw, I notice the wrt54g has some option called "operating mode" that can get set to gateway or router.   put it in gateway mode (apparently router mode is for more advanced features or functionality like sending a routing table to another router)

Comment: actually i'm not sure whether the LAN side has to be same subnet as WAN side, perhaps not.  It would be a step forward if you can access the linksys interface when you plug a computer into it.. I haven't used a "Router" in a while, just a router/modem and  my experience which should apply, is that as long as the computer plugging into it is on the same subnet e.g. router of 192.168.1.1  computer 192.168.1.x then it should work. Are you finding that when you plug your computer into the linksys you  can access the interface but can't when you plug your gateway into it the linksys?

Comment: @chobo2 ok.. i've found out with the WRT, NAT ON, it functions as a router, so I presume you want it on. and with it on, apparently, you need the LAN side to be a different subnet to the WAN side.. sorry about this.. it turns out somewhat different to the router/modems i'm used to.

Comment: @chobo2 DHCP on both isp gateway, and  on WRT54G router is fine, no clash. The DHCP from the isp gateway won't reach the Linksys WRT's LAN side.  So you do actually want a different subnet on each side of the linksys WRT. Set your linksys WRT LAN IP and the DHCP to a different subnet than the isp gateway's DHCP.  The following isn't necessary, but ideally you'd want to turn NAT off on the isp gateway but it is not possible with yours. Maybe a generic router/modem will work in place of your ISPs one, where you can turn NAT off.

Comment: @chobo2 you could turn NAT off on your linksys WRT but from what i've heard, then it's just a switch. so  i think you'd lose some functionality you want.

Comment: @chobo2 btw you always have a choice DHCP or static, but DHCP on both won't create any clash. So if in a situation where you can't turn DHCP off on the isp gateway, fine, and it's worth keeping it on on the linksys wrt54g, then not having to set computer statically. And as mentioned, different subnet is key!

Answer (score 1):

If your ISP device is handing out 192.168.1.x, then you can simply assign your linksys to still do DHCP/NAT but use 192.168.0.x range. Your computers will end up with a gateway of 192.168.0.1 (the linksys router) and your linksys router will have a gateway of 192.168.1.1 (the ISP device). Traffic will get routed fine between both gateways and out to the internet. The only problem that this type of setup will cause is with any need to port forward as you will need to port forward from the ISP device to your router and then from your router to the given computer, but it is entirely possible to do. When ISP devices are required to do DHCP, this is the most common setup to make everything work without issue.